# how get the result of Future without using "await"

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future, specs2

I want to get the result of a Future without blocking operations.
If I write my code with "await", it works but it is not good for me because it is blocking:

```
val t: Future[MatchResult[Personne]] = db.getPersonne(userId).map(_.get must beEqualTo(personne))
t.await
```

I tried to change my code with `map`:

```
 val r: Future[MatchResult[Personne]] = db.getPersonne(userId).map(_.get must beEqualTo(personne))
   r.map {
     case r@isWhatIExpected => r
     case isNot => isNot
   }
```

but I have this error:

> found   :
>   scala.concurrent.Future[org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult[Personne]]
>       [error]  required: org.specs2.specification.create.InterpolatedFragment

Comment: When you are in a `Future` context, you cannot get out of it without waiting. However, you can use `onComplete` to consume the result when it is ready.

Comment: Your question seems to be about spec2 not futures in general. In general you can use `fut.foreach` or `fut.map` to continue working with the values of a future.

Answer (score 2):

Using Specs2 as it appears, there are helpers to test async functions.

```
import org.specs2.concurrent.{ExecutionEnv => EE}

"Foo" in { implicit ee: EE => // take care of ee
  myAsyncFunWithFuture must beEqualTo(expectedVal).await(timeToWait)
}
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand your answer. you can more explain

Comment: There is no need to use Scala `Await` to test using Specs2, as long as you properly end with `.await` helper, which is not the case with the `map`ed val.

Comment: Afaik, you don't even need the import ExecutionEnv, nor the implicit

Comment: C4stor in this answer you use await but it is blocking

Comment: @C4stor if you carefully read the Specs2 [documentation](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.8.7/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#execution), you can read "The await/attempt methods require an implicit org.specs2.concurrent.ExecutionEnv"

Answer (score 0):

@user4650183 I think I don't understand your question then. Something somewhere has to wait, or block if you prefer, on the result before using it.